# Use of open/closed sets in Kolgomorov's Introductory Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am reading Introductory Real Analysis by Kolmogorov & Fomin. In chapter 3 "Topological Spaces", at the beginning a definition of a topology and topological space is given, and some examples. I do not understand one of those examples, which is the following:

> **Example 4:** Let $T$ be the set $\{a, b\}$, consisting of just two points $a$
> and $b$, and let the open sets in $T$ be $T$ itself, the empty set and the
> single-element set $\{b\}$. Then the two properties in Definition 1
> (Definition of a Topology) are satisfied, and $T$ is a topological
> space. The closed sets in this space are $T$ itself, the empty set and
> the set $\{a\}$. Note that the closure of $\{b\}$ is the whole space $T$.

What I do not understand, in particular, is how come they can "choose" that $\{b\}$ is open and $\{a\}$ is closed? Why would that be the case? If you're defining an arbitrary set can you decide what is open and what is closed?

Comment: A topological space is _by definition_ a pair $(S, \tau)$ where $S$ is some _set_ and $\tau$ is a _set of subsets of $S$_ satisfying the properties of a topology. In theory, you can grab any set and _choose_ $\tau$ however you like (as long as it satisfies the definition). In practice, you will be interested in particular sets (e.g. an interval, an open disc, some set of functions) and the topology will be sort of already chosen for you in advance (e.g. the topology of the real line generated by the absolute-value norm, the usual Euclidean topology of the plane, the sup-norm topology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\{b\}$ is open because the topology that we are working with here is $\tau=\bigl\{\emptyset,\{b\},\{a,b\}\bigr\}$ and because, by definition, a subset $A$ of $\{a,b\}$ is open if (and only if) $A\in\tau$. And once you know that $\{b\}$ is open, its complement, i.e. $\{a\}$ is *by definition* closed. There is no “choice” involved at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, one can define any topology $\tau$, in this case they decided to use  $\tau=\bigl\{\emptyset, \{b\},  \{a, b\} \bigl\} $, and therefore the rest is just following the definitions. Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.